# JavaScript Algorithm Scripting

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the exercises on freeCodeCamp and have stuck on this task:

> Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains
>   all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.
>
> For example, ["hello", "Hello"], should return true because all of the
>   letters in the second string are present in the first, ignoring case.
>
> The arguments ["hello", "hey"] should return false because the string
>   "hello" does not contain a "y".

**My code is fully working except this arguments: ["hello", "hey"]**

Please, help me to understand what is the problem.

My code:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  let arr1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let arr2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: You are returning *true* or *false* on the very first test, you need to test every letter. Consider using [*Array.prototype.every*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjx25bru6zeAhXGfn0KHQ7_CykQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fevery&usg=AOvVaw0jff1V5W6NdiwTvdLQ7kA3) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning in the first iteration of your for loop regardless of whether the loop is finished or not. You want to go *all* the way through the loop unless you find a reason to return (like you didn't find a letter). If you make it through the loop you're good and can return `true`.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let arr1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let arr2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      return false;  // found a false value, you can return
    }
  }
  return true  // made it through the loop without finding a false value.

}
console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));
console.log(mutation(["hello", "HEllo"]));
```